# Locate an image within a specific region of the screen using Python's Pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

Using the pyautogui module in python I'd like to locate an image on the screen, then locate an image within that image. How would I go about doing this? I have visualizations attached below. Thank you.

[image: Locating the first image on the screen]

[image: Locating the second image within the first image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are three options, in order of increasing complexity:

1. use the pyautogui's built-in function - `locateOnScreen`
2. use a color-based approach (described below)
3. if the color-based approach is not satisfactory, you could have a detection neural network (as YoloV4 or ResNet) trained to detect the sub-image in the main image.

#### Color-based approach

Try to first find the coordinates of the Track 10 area and take a screenshot.

```
import pyautogui
import numpy as np

(x, y) = pyautogui.position()
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
img = np.array(screenshot)
```

Take the row of the image, say you are at (100, 1000), then slice the screenshot array and search for the rgb values of the color that you need:

```
x_index = 100

def get_y_index():
    green = (0, 255, 0)
    row = img[x_index]
    for idx, px in enumerate(row):
        if px == green:
            return idx
    return None

y_index = get_y_index()
```

The coordinates of the green thingie would be `(x_index, y_index)`.